# How to run AngularJS on JSFiddle?

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I have a trouble with starting an example in JSFiddle, it's simple code with AngularJS module, but I get a error with injecting module.

Javascript code:

```
angular
  .module('App', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'Hello';
  });
```

Html code:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  {{ text }}
</div>
```

Please, help me to fix it.
    [Link to my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Skryabind/rbhuce5z/10/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rbhuce5z/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change you javascript Load Type configuration. For example:

`No wrap - in <body>` or `<head>`

[image]

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbhuce5z/16/)

Comment: You don't need to set the framework there, he has it imported in the external resources this would create a warning stating you're trying to load multiple instances of angularjs.

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren, Did not see it. My bad. Thank you. Updated.